# Sorting A Nested List

Tags: list, sorting, scheme, racket

I want to sort a nested list of Strings in alphabetical order, for example:

```
(list 
   (list "Worcestershire" "Edinburgh")
   (list "Suffolk" "Liverpool")
   (list "Norfolk" "York")
   (list "Lincoln" "Malmesbury")
   (list "Glasgow" "Desmond"))
```

So for this one, I just want to sort it by the first word in each of the sub-lists (please ignore the second word for now). My code is here:

```
(define (sort lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [else (insert (first (first lst)) (second (first lst))
                      (sort (rest lst)))]))

;; helper function
(define (insert element1 element2 lst)
   (cond [(empty? lst) (list element1 element2)]
         [(string<=? element1 (first lst)) (cons element1 lst)]
         [else (cons (first lst) (insert element1 element2 (rest lst)))]))
```

The program should theoretically produce

```
(list 
    (list "Glasgow" "Desmond")
    (list "Lincoln" "Malmesbury")
    (list "Norfolk" "York")
    (list "Suffolk" "Liverpool")
    (list "Worcestershire" "Edinburgh"))
```

But right now it is producing

```
(list "Glasgow" "Desmond" "Lincoln" "Malmesbury" 
      "Norfolk" "Suffolk" "Worcestershire" "York")
```

The list is not nested, and it is even missing some of the components! Could someone check my code, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting list of lists by their first element in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056854/sorting-list-of-lists-by-their-first-element-in-scheme)

Comment: @amalloy Sorry but not quite, ideally I want to sort by insertion (as seen in the code section there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
(define (sort lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) empty]
        [else (insert (first (first lst)) 
                      (second (first lst))
                      (sort (rest lst)))]))
```

This obviously assumes `lst` is `[(a1 b1) (a2 b2) ... (an bn)]`, then it defines (writing in pseudocode)

```
sort [(a1 b1) (a2 b2) ... (an bn)]
 == 
insert a1 b1 (sort [(a2 b2) ... (an bn)])
```

and `sort [] == []`.

Right from this we see that it must hold that

```
sort [(a1 b1)] == insert a1 b1 (sort [])
               == insert a1 b1 []
  == [(a1 b1)]
```

which gives us part of the definition of `insert` right there, before we even started writing it ourselves.

And so, your definition of `insert` must be corrected as

```
;; helper function
(define (insert e1 e2 lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst)     (list (list e1 e2))]
        [(string<=? e1 (first (first lst)))
                          (cons (list e1 e2) lst)]
        [else   (cons (first lst) 
                      (insert e1 e2 (rest lst)))]))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you (:

Comment: you're welcome. :) if you post more Scheme/Racket questions, you can ping me here, to call my attention to it. :)

Comment: sorry for bothering you again, but how would you sort the second element in the list without messing up the order that the first element was sorted in? I've tried that for hours and couldn't get it right. The second element should only sort itself when the first element is the same. I wrote an example there, could you check it out? Thanks.

Comment: sure, just post *new* question please. I've rolled back your edit, because edits must not invalidate existing answers. in your new question, you can include link to this one as a background, if you like.

Comment: (you will even get more points when / if someone upvotes your new question, and / or you accept an answer :) ) but to give you a hint, `[(string<=? e1 (first (first lst))) ...` compares just `e1` and `(first (first lst))`, with the `string<=?`, right? so you'd use `string<?`, and the second test with `string=?` for `e1` and `string<=?` for `e2`. and combine the tests with `or` and `and`.

Comment: as in, test whether `e1` is smaller than `1st1st`, OR { `e1` *equals* `1st1st` AND *`e2`* is smaller-or-equal than .... (what?) }.

Comment: So that's what I was missing - I kept testing the Or part but never checked if e1 is smaller than (first (first lst))!

Comment: Yes!!! I completely patched out the error. Definitely would accept your answer twice if I could!!

Comment: glad to be of help. :) you can still post the new question, and even post your own answer there at the same time if you so choose. more opportunity to get some points, too.